# What does this forward slash do

Tags: c, division, forward, slash

```
for (n=0;n<sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr); n++)
```

i got this piece of code and don't know what this '/' does.

is it just a arithmetic operater and means 'divide by' ?

'arr' is my array, so does it just divide the size of my array by the size of the array itself?

I'm confused

Comment: There is a difference between `sizeof(arr)` (the size of the entire array) and `sizeof(*arr)` (the size of an array element).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/` is the division operator and `sizeof arr / sizeof *arr` is the idiomatic way to get the number of elements of an array (number of bytes of the array / number of bytes of the first element of the array).